# Clear Context using persistence CoreData

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, swift

I would like to know if you have any way to "clean up" my `context` using `Core Data`.

For I have a problem in that when I update the application, even after saving the records in the database, also keeps in context. Therefore every time will show on the screen these records shows duplicate the same as it takes the bank and the temporary standing in context.

Obs .: I checked and does not duplicate record in the database.

Comment: Your question isn't exactly clear.  Are you looking for the `reset` method of `NSManagedObjectContext`?

Comment: Yup. I have the temporary objects in my context. I want to save them on the bench and remove them from my context

Comment: From the docs for `reset`....  'All the receiver's managed objects are “forgotten.”'

Comment: The Breaking of how long? For he is still getting in my context

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: Sorry, the Breaking context of how long the objects disappear from my context? Why objects are still in my context